# How to you get the value of the selected choice in the Django Admin Site FilePathField dropdown?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

If I use Django's FilePathField in a model such as below,

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    fileName = models.FilePathField(path='static/myfiles/')
```

It enables me to get the choices and assign a fileName to a record/row in the table using admin site. My question is how to you get the value of the selected choice in the Django Admin Site FilePathField dropdown?

Comment: If you want to see a file, then you need to make it `FileField` or you can write html to display your file with a link from `fileName`

Comment: How one use FilePathField then? Also a link from fileName is just a path? They say FileField is for upload while FilePathField is for existing ones.

Comment: what do you mean by showing file?

Comment: By showing the file I meant in the template I want to access the filename of the chosen file in the admin site where FilePathField has given the choices.